# Evaluate the line integral when the function has$ x,y,z$ variables and the curve has only $x,y$ components

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to evaluate the line integral $\int_{C}^{}(x^2+y^2+z)ds$ where $C$ is the curve parameterized by $\vec r(t) = <\sin 3t, \cos 3t>, {0}\lt{t}\lt \frac{\pi}{4}$
The answer given is $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{6}+\frac{3\pi}{4}.$

I evaluated ds as $ds = 3 dt$. Substituting $x=\sin 3t, y=\cos 3t, z=0$, and  integrating from $t=0$ to $t=\frac{\pi}{4}$, the answer that I get is $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ .
What am I doing wrong? Am I not handling the argument $3t$ correctly?

Comment: Please send the full question.

Comment: There seems to be an obvious abuse of notation as $\vec{r}$ should live in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I guess the rigorous form should be $\vec{r}(t) = \left(\sin 3t, \cos 3t, 0\right)$.

Comment: The question as written does not make sense. If $z=0$, then $x^2+y^2=1$ and we have $$\int_Cx^2+y^2+z\:ds = \int_Cds = \frac{3\pi}{4}$$ or the perimeter of the unit circle from angle $0$ to angle $\frac{3\pi}{4}$

Comment: Evaluate  $\int_{C}(x^2+y^2+z)ds$ where C is the curve with parameterization  $\vec r(t) = ⟨sin(3t),cos(3t)⟩ ,  0\lt t\lt\frac{3\pi}{4}$

This is the full question. As Munshi, pointed out, I also get the answer as $\frac{3\pi}{4}$  The question is taken from https://math.libretexts.org/Courses/Monroe_Community_College/MTH_212_Calculus_III/Chapter_15%3A_Vector_Fields_Line_Integrals_and_Vector_Theorems/15.2%3A_Line_Integrals

Comment: Sorry, the domain for t is $0\le t\le \frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: What you are doing wrong is expecting whoever wrote this exercise will always remember to change the integrand appropriately. In this case, they copied-and-pasted, but forgot to update the integrand to make sense. This is evident from their hint to use the "two-variable version" which itself clearly states that the function being integrated should have two variables only.  Unfortunately it is not clear what integrand was supposed to be used. So there is no way to solve the problem.